# How to create a csv file and write data to it,without storing physical file locally?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, csv

I have tried to export DataTable data to csv file.I have followed below steps.

- First I have created a csv file in Temp folder.
- Then I'm storing DataTable data in csv file of Temp folder.

**Code:**

[image]

But my requirement is, I need to create a csv file and write data to it without creating any physical file.I need to avoid storing file in physical path like Temp folder.

How can I do that.

Comment: CSV is a way of you store a list of data in a file! Why don't you just store your data inside a `List<ModelType>` in the memory, and finally store it as a `csv` file?

Comment: Then use a memory stream which will emulate a physical file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in creating a specific file if it is not going to be stored.
I'm realy unsure what your goal is. If you don't want to create a File you can just keep it in a `string` or save it to a Database but then the point of a ".csv"-file-extension is gone.
If you just don't want it to be visible you coud set the "hidden"-property of the file.

Or if you just want to create it at the same time as you save data to it, you can try to remove the step for the file-creation. I think if you write it to a non existent file, the file will be created automatically

Comment: I have removed File.Create() and File.WriteAllText() and instead  converted string builder data to bytes and then moved it to memory stream and used memory stream data to create a file at azure blob. It worked.Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

A CSV file is just a regular file with text thats formatted a certian way. You can use a `MemoryStream` to write data to a stream in memory that you can then use to write to a file or another source at a later point.

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using(var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream ) {
    writer.Write(...);
}
```